# Help finding specific discrete math book. Text provided

Tags: discrete-mathematics, book-recommendation

I have on my notebook this example copied from the beginning of the book:

$$p: \text{Mathematicians are generous} $$
$$q: \text{Spiders hate algebra} $$

$$\text{(i) } p \lor \bar{q}: \text{Mathematicians are generous and spiders don't hate algebra}$$
$$\text{(ii) } \overline{(q \land p)}: \text{It's not the case that spiders hate algebra neither mathematicians are generous}$$
$$\text{(iii) } \bar{p} \to q: \text{If mathematicians aren't generous then spiders will hate algebra}$$
$$\text{(iv) } \bar{p} \iff \bar{q}: \text{Mathematicians aren't generous if and only if spiders doesn't hate algebra}$$

I was reading it over a year ago in a digital library from my university, then one day it was gone from the catalogue.

Like I mentioned, the example is from the beginning of the book so If anyone remember reading the same book that uses spiders as examples I'll be thankful.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't help you with what you want, but I believe whatever that book was, there are always great substitutes. BTW, $\lor$ means **logical or**, *not* **logical and**, so that $p\lor \bar q$ means *Mathematicians are generous **or** spiders don't hate algebra, or both.*

Comment: Similarly, $\overline{(q \land p)}$ means: *It's not the case that spiders hate algebra **and simultaneously** mathematicians are generous*. In other words, we won't see a day when mathematicians are generous *and* spiders hate algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears on page 8 of "Discrete Mathematics for New Technology"
(Second Edition), by Rowan Garnier and John Taylor (2002). Here's an image:[image]